# EC2 Instances are not shown in the Cluster Infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have been trying to create an ECS Cluster using EC2 but there seems to be a problem when attaching the EC2 instances to the ECS Cluster. When I provision the resources using terraform the infrastructure of the cluster does not show the instances and the tasks stay on the pending status (even though the EC2 instances have been created as the EC2 page shows in the AWS console).
I have tried to be permissive on the security group for testing. I've also created an internet gateway, created a NAT gateway, and mapped a public IP on my subnets but nothing seems to solve this problem.
Here is the code for my VPC and all the resources:

```
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
  }
}

# Public Subnet for NAT Gateway
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
 vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
 cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, 0)
 map_public_ip_on_launch = true
 availability_zone       = "us-east-1a"
}

# Private Subnets
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
 vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
 cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, 1)
 map_public_ip_on_launch = true
 availability_zone       = "us-east-1a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet2" {
 vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
 cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, 2)
 map_public_ip_on_launch = true
 availability_zone       = "us-east-1b"
}

# Elastic IP for NAT Gateway
resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
  domain = "vpc"
}

# NAT Gateway
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gateway" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
}

# Internet Gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}

# Route Table for Public Subnet
resource "aws_route_table" "public_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }
}

# Associate Public Route Table with Public Subnet
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_subnet_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_route_table.id
}

# Route Table for Private Subnets
resource "aws_route_table" "private_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.nat_gateway.id
  }
}

# Associate Private Route Table with Private Subnets
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_subnet_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_route_table.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_subnet2_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet2.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_route_table.id
}



######################################## Security Group ###################################################

resource "aws_security_group" "security_group" {
 name   = "ecs-security-group"
 vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

 ingress {
   from_port   = 0
   to_port     = 0 
   protocol    = -1
   self        = "false"
   cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
   description = "any"
 }
 
  ingress {
   from_port   = 22
   to_port     = 22
   protocol    = "tcp"
   cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
   description = "Allow SSH access from anywhere"
 }
 
  egress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    description = "Allow outbound HTTPS traffic to ECR"
  }

 egress {
   from_port   = 0
   to_port     = 0 
   protocol    = "-1"
   cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
 }
}
```

I have also checked here on Stackoverflow this problem and one of the solutions is to set a user data for the instances like this code :
`echo ECS_CLUSTER=${aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.name} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;`
But it also does not seem to work.

Here is the code for my ECS, auto scaling and load balancer:

```
######################################## ECS Cluster ######################################
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "ecs_cluster" {
 name = "${var.environment}-ecs-cluster"
}



####################################### ECS Node Role ######################################

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_node_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_node_role" {
  name_prefix        = "${var.environment}-ecs-node-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_node_doc.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_node_role_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_node_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs_node" {
  name_prefix = "${var.environment}-ecs-node-profile"
  path        = "/ecs/instance/"
  role        = aws_iam_role.ecs_node_role.name
}

################################# Security Group for ECS #########################################

resource "aws_security_group" "ecs_node_sg" {
  name_prefix = "${var.environment}-ecs-node-sg-"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 65535
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

##################################### Launch Template ######################################
resource "aws_launch_template" "ecs_lt" {
 name_prefix   = "${var.environment}-ecs-launch-template"
 image_id      = "ami-098e21427471ececc" 
 instance_type = "g4dn.xlarge"
 vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]

 key_name               = "${var.company_name}_ecs_access"
 iam_instance_profile { arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_node.arn }
 monitoring { enabled = true }

 block_device_mappings {
   device_name = "/dev/xvda"
   ebs {
     volume_size = 45
     volume_type = "gp2"
   }
 }

 tag_specifications {
   resource_type = "instance"
   tags = {
     Name = "ecs-instance"
   }
 }

 user_data = base64encode(<<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      echo ECS_CLUSTER=${aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.name} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
    EOF
  )
}


##################################### Auto Scaling Group #####################################
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs_asg" {
    name_prefix = "${var.environment}-ecs-asg"
    vpc_zone_identifier = var.subnet_list
    min_size            = 1
    max_size            = 3
    desired_capacity    = 2
    health_check_grace_period = 0
    health_check_type         = "EC2"
    protect_from_scale_in     = false


    launch_template {
        id      = aws_launch_template.ecs_lt.id
        version = "$Latest"
    }

    tag {
        key                 = "Name"
        value               = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.name
        propagate_at_launch = true
    }

    tag {
        key                 = "AmazonECSManaged"
        value               = ""
        propagate_at_launch = true
    }
}

#################################### Capacity Providers #################################
resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "ecs_capacity_provider" {
 name = "${var.environment}_capacity_provider"

 auto_scaling_group_provider {
   auto_scaling_group_arn = aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_asg.arn

   managed_scaling {
     maximum_scaling_step_size = 2
     minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
     status                    = "ENABLED"
     target_capacity           = 3
   }
 }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" "example" {
 cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.name

 capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs_capacity_provider.name]

 default_capacity_provider_strategy {
   base              = 1
   weight            = 100
   capacity_provider = aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs_capacity_provider.name
 }
}


####################################### Task Role #########################################
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_task_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_role" {
  name_prefix        = "${var.environment}-ecs-task-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_doc.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_exec_role" {
  name_prefix        = "${var.environment}-ecs-exec-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_doc.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_exec_role_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

########################################## CloudWatch Logs ####################################
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "ecs" {
  name              = "/ecs/demo"
  retention_in_days = 14
}


################################# Task Definition ######################################
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task_definition" {
 family             = "${var.environment}-ecs-task"
 network_mode       = "awsvpc"
 task_role_arn      = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.arn 
 execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec_role.arn
 cpu                = 512
 runtime_platform {
   operating_system_family = "LINUX"
   cpu_architecture        = "X86_64"
 }
 container_definitions = jsonencode([
   {
     name      = "${var.environment}_${var.company_name}_container",
     image     = var.ecr_repo_url,
     cpu       = var.ecs_cpu,
     memory    = var.ecs_memory,
     essential = true,
     portMappings = [
       {
         containerPort = 80
         hostPort      = 80
         protocol      = "tcp"
       }
     ],
     logConfiguration = {
      logDriver = "awslogs",
      options = {
        "awslogs-region"        = "us-east-1",
        "awslogs-group"         = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.ecs.name,
        "awslogs-stream-prefix" = "app"
      }
     }
   }
 ])
}


################################# ECS Service #######################################
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs_service" {
 name            = "${var.environment}-ecs-service"
 cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.id
 task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_definition.arn
 desired_count   = 2

 network_configuration {
   subnets         = var.subnet_list
   security_groups = [var.security_group_id]
 }

 force_new_deployment = true
 placement_constraints {
   type = "distinctInstance"
 }

 triggers = {
   redeployment = timestamp()
 }

 capacity_provider_strategy {
   capacity_provider = aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs_capacity_provider.name
   weight            = 100
 }

 load_balancer {
   target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.ecs_tg.arn
   container_name   = "${var.environment}_${var.company_name}_container"
   container_port   = 80
 }

 depends_on = [aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_asg]
}

################################# Application Load Balancer ################################
resource "aws_lb" "ecs_alb" {
 name               = "${var.environment}-ecs-alb"
 internal           = false
 load_balancer_type = "application"
 security_groups    = [var.security_group_id]
 subnets            = var.subnet_list

 tags = {
   Name = "ecs-alb"
 }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "ecs_alb_listener" {
 load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.ecs_alb.arn
 port              = 80
 protocol          = "HTTP"

 default_action {
   type             = "forward"
   target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.ecs_tg.arn
 }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "ecs_tg" {
 name        = "${var.environment}-ecs-target-group"
 port        = 80
 protocol    = "HTTP"
 target_type = "ip"
 vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

 health_check {
   path = "/"
 }
}
```

Note that the variables are being passed from the VPC module to the ECS module. The variable subnet_list only contain the resources "subnet" and "subnet2" and does not contain the "public_subnet". "subnet" and "subnet2" were meant to not have map_public_ip_on_launch set to true but for the sake of trying I have changed the value.

Does someone have a hint of what might be causing this problem?

Comment: You aren't creating any EC2 instances through Terraform as far as I can tell. You mention autoscaling in your question, but there is no autoscaling group being created in the Terraform code you posted. Please edit your question to include the details of how the EC2 instances are being created.

Comment: Just edited now, I've accidentally posted the wrong code.

Comment: Have you done an SSH into the EC2 instance(s) and checked the ECS Agent Log for any errors? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/logs.html

Comment: I am also not being able to connect to the EC2 instance using SSH, even though the there is a .pem key configured in the ec2 instances to connect. I got this error when trying to connect:
ssh: connect to host ec2-3-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out.   
This is the command to connect:
 ssh -i "my_access_key.pem" root@ec2-3-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Is your Terraform configuration different from any other over the internet (because it does not look like)? Try to compare your code to other configurations for ECS using Terraform

Comment: I've compared many times my configuration to many tutorials and it does not seem to have a significant difference. The only think I can think now is that  what might be causing this problem is the ECR being private, but that does not explain why I am not being able to SSH the instance.

Comment: Not sure which AMI you are using, but usually there is no root user for SSH enabled. If it's Amazon Linux, the default user is `ec2-user`.

Comment: I've tried "ec2-user", "root", "ubuntu" and none of them work.